# VBA Objects Named Classes in Object Browser

Tags: vba, excel

This question may sound childish but her "innocent looks" have left her pass unnoticed to all of my 7 VBA books. Why in the object browser we see Objects listed as classes
[image]

this ..."lively" example shows the Range in the brown colored circle which is an Object (thus Object Browser) i'm OK with that.

- But why up in the Header in the Black rectangular we see the list that contains the Range named as classes?
- And why as we see in the red circle the OB has objects marked with that symbol which is the same that a fella sees whenever he clicks in the VBE Insert --> Class Module (shown in the second pic)

As we can see in this picture 
[image]

Comment: A Range **object** is an instance of the Range **class**. Object Browser is really "Types of Object Browser" - you are browsing classes and their methods/properties, not actual objects.

Comment: There are also some actual objects listed there - e.g. `ThisWorkbook` - and those are shown in bold text. If you click on them, however, the description shows something like `Class ThisWorkbook` which seems inaccurate

Comment: @barrowc `ThisWorkbook` is a property of the Excel `Application` class: it returns an object of type `Workbook`.  There's also a `ThisWorkbook` class listed under the "VBAProject" library - this corresponds to the "ThisWorkbook" code module visible in the Project Explorer tree view.

Comment: If I answer this question of yours as well then I will feel like I am already writing a book for you for free :p @TimWilliams is absolutely right here and this can be easily seen on the bottom left of your 2nd screenshot. `That` highlighted `object` is a part of `Range Class`

Comment: Well i think i'm getting the point. Books should clearly explain such concepts! Thank you all. Never write a book for me but for all as stack curious users. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilty as charged. I was new to VBA but this was an atrocious question!!!

Comments answer the question in entirety!